# When can Windows Activate?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-activation

I tried to activate Windows, but its resulting in the message *"Windows can't activate. Try again later"*. I then tried Help and Support, but it does not discuss the message its providing.

So my question is, When can Windows activate? What is a good time to perform the procedure?

Or maybe, How do I get an accurate message so I know what the problem is, instead of wasting my time with incorrect messages?

---

[image]

Comment: Do you have a working network connection?

Comment: @Hennes - yes, I have a network connection. I just verified using ping from the command line.

Comment: Ok, just asking. One obvious reason would have been no recognized network cards. (And hence no driver download and no activation). You could try [slmrg /ato](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn502540.aspx).

Comment: The product key is it the generic key that is assigned to everyone that performed the upgrade or is it an individual retail Windows 10 license which has been activated on the machine before (or a different machine)?

Answer (score 1):

If the net activation doesn't work, skip it and use the oldskool `slui`

Run `slui 4` from the run prompt brought up with <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

This will ask you to activate using the phone system

Comment: Thanks TD. I'll keep it in mind as an alternate procedure. Do you happen to know when we are allowed to activate Windows? And why does Microsoft limit when we can do it?

Comment: @jww there's no limit on *when*, only on *how many* times. when OTI activation doesn't work, use OTT